# Reading and Writing to a file in C++ integer by integer

Tags: c++, file, fstream, ifstream, ofstream

I have a piece of code to write elements of an array to a file (serialize) and then read it back (deserialize)
Here it is :

```
#include<stdio.h>

void serialize(int *arr,int n,FILE *fp)
{
    int i=0;
    for( ; i<=n-1 ; i++)
        fprintf(fp,"%d ",arr[i]); // The elements of array go into the file
}

void deserialize(FILE *fp)
{
    int temp;
    while(1)
    {
        if(fscanf(fp,"%d",&temp))
            printf("%d ",temp);        // The Contents of file tree.txt are written to console
        else
            break;
    }
}


int main()
{
    int arr[] = {20,8,-1,-1,22,-1,-1};

    FILE *fp = fopen("tree.txt", "w");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        puts("Could not open file");
        return 0;
    }
    serialize(arr,n, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    fp = fopen("tree.txt", "r");
    deserialize(fp);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

How to achieve this using the objects ofstream and ifstream in C++?

Comment: It is unclear what your question is. First your program does not compile. Second it won't do what you describe. So using stream objects would be pointless.

Comment: 1. Make sure your integers are separated, probably using spaces. 2. Make sure you verify that `fscanf()` (or any alternative used) was successful.

Comment: @mkaes.. apologies.. I had trouble while copying line by line and formatting here.. Now the code is fine. I am able to compile just the copy-paste of this code

Comment: @DietmarKühl.. Hello.. I have done both 1 and 2 you have mentioned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

object streams operator overloading requires to provide an overload for a given type. Which means you need to wrap your custom array, for instance like

```
struct my_array
{
   int *arr;
   int n;
};
```

and then define the overloads

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const my_array& foo)
{
   //same as serialize
   int i=0;
   for( ; i<=foo.n-1 ; i++)
      os << foo.arr[i];
   return os;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, my_array& dt)
{
    //do something 
    return is;
}
```

There is an issue with your code. serialization and deserialization are not strictly inverse operations. This is due to the fact that when reading you have no clue on how many values you are supposed to read. Thus trying to serialize your data and then something else and read back will **always** fail.

```
fstream s;
my_array a;
bar b;
s << a << b;
...
my_array x;
bar y;
s >> x >> y; //endof, failbit set
```

Here not only `y ! = b`, but `x != a`. To add insult to the injury, the content of both `x` and `y` [will be different depending on whether you are c++11 or not](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt).

Answer (score 2):

You can use other approach: `ostream_iterator` and `istream_iterator`

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main(int, char **)
{
  int arr[] = {20,8,-1,-1,22,-1,-1};

  // write to console
  std::copy(arr, arr + 7, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));

  // write on file
  std::cout << std::endl << "Writing on file" << std::endl;

  std::ofstream myOfile("./out.dat");

  if (myOfile.is_open())
  {
    std::ostream_iterator<int> out_iter(myOfile, " ");
    std::copy(arr, arr + 7, out_iter);

    myOfile.close();
  }

  // read from file
  std::cout << std::endl << "Reading from file" << std::endl;

  std::ifstream myIfile("./out.dat");

  if (myIfile.is_open())
  {
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(myIfile),
              std::istream_iterator<int>(),
              std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));

    myIfile.close();
  }

  return 0;
}
```